# Intermediate pool server

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, server

Is it possible to make "intermediate" pool server, which will be gateway to real pool?

I have about 200 pc's, each pc connects to my intermediate pool using own login pass. Intermediate pool should get work (using stratum) from real pool using own login and pass, and submit shares using own login password.

[image: Gateway Example]

Answer (score 2):

There are bitcoin mining proxies, some code is available on github (use the search).
For example https://github.com/cdhowie/Bitcoin-mining-proxy
(*pls make your own security evaluations on opensource code)

Im not aware of a "intermediate pool", of course proxies are popular for mining.

Comment: Thanks, but is there is a solution in C/C++?

Comment: @Roman While I agree that this specific example uses PHP to relay the *getwork* protocol instead of *stratum*, and that that's not wise, languages like Java or Go often outperform C/C++. Although performance hardly seems relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are lots of ways to do this, the easiest of which is likely using Startum Proxy as described here: https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=4831.0

Also I found something which may be able to help here on SE: [I have 8 Antminers, is there a way I could change their pool credentials all at the same time like through ssh with a script](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/i-have-8-antminers-is-there-a-way-i-could-change-their-pool-credentials-all-at/22551?noredirect=1#22551)

It should be noted that the Stratum Mining Proxy was developed to port old machinery (early ASICs, mainly) to Stratum by having the proxy create getwork from a stratum request for you.

I would look at some open source pools: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software#Mining_Pool_Servers_.28backend.29

Getwork has a great feature built in called "hostlist", which was created by slush and is described here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork#hostlist

I am not sure how this transitioned into stratum or getblocktemplate.

It has not been included in most pool software and is not native to bitcoind (it is a miner-side protocol and thus does not NEED to be in bitcoind): https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poolservers

Until last year hostlist had transitioned into more modern mining software, I would recommend testing this function before getting too far into development ;) Unfortunately I do not have the time right now to test this but hopefully this puts you on the right path of hacking together something which works for you.